# Redirecting route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a problem with Laravel on redirecting route; what I was doing is this:

[image]

As you can see I am trying to make a `href` value for a button when the select option is changed. I wanted to redirect it to a show controller using:

```
var deptHref = "{{{action('AdminDocumentsController@show')}}}";
var actionDeptHref = deptHref + '/' + id;
```

but then when I try to run it it gives me this URL on my browser:

[image]

I wonder where the "%7Badmin_documents%7D" is coming from, because I was expecting to get "admin-documents/show/8"?

What I did in my route is this:

[image]

That's why I was expecting in my browser URL is "admin-documents/show/8".

I also checked my `php artisan` routes to see what I have:

[image]

So I have two " admin-documents.show " is this affecting my routes? If this is affecting it why does the:

```
  var href = "{{{action('AdminDocumentsController@create')}}}";
  var id = $('#department-options').val();
  href = href + "/" + id;
```

is working?

Answer (score 0):

Using 3 curly braces makes Laravel escape your HTML, use only 2:

```
var href = "{{action('AdminDocumentsController@create')}}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route expects {id}, which you'd normally supply with the params using the helper (http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls), in your case however, you can't supply it because it's dynamic, so one way to do it is to use absolute urls. So

```
var href = "{{{action('AdminDocumentsController@show')}}}";
var id = $('#department-options').val();
href = href + "/" + id;
```

would become

```
var href = "/admin-documents/show/" + $('#department-options').val();
```

Comment: but the create is working, dunno why it is not in show. cuz it works just fine with create thats why i tried to do it again. can you tell me why? tnx for the reply

Comment: Hold on, I haven't been reading well enough, created does not require the id, the show route does. I'll edit my answer to avoid confusion.